# How to deploy a Java Web Application (.war) on tomcat?

Tags: java, web-applications, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I have a `.war` file of a Java Web Application. Now I want to upload it to my ftp server so that I can execute it.

What steps I should perform to run it?

The context path of the webapp is /mywebapp

#### Edit

Actually, my ftp server name is ftp://bilgin.ath.cx/ and I have uploaded my *TestWebApp.war* file to this dir: ftp://bilgin.ath.cx/web

Then what should be the URL to access the *index.html* page of the webapplication

#### #2 Edit

`Tomcat` is listening on `8082`

Apache access Tomcat with jk connector.

Comment: What does the instructions for bilgin.ath.cx say?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As others pointed out, the most straightforward way to deploy a WAR is to copy it to the `webapps` of the Tomcat install. Another option would be to use the manager application **if** it is installed (this is not always the case), **if** it's properly configured (i.e. if you have the credentials of a user assigned to the appropriate group) **and if** it you can access it over an insecure network like Internet (but this is very unlikely and you didn't mention any VPN access). So this leaves you with the `webapp`directory.

Now, if Tomcat is installed and running on `bilgin.ath.cx` (as this is the machine where you uploaded the files), I noticed that Apache is listening to port `80` on that machien so I would bet that Tomcat is not directly exposed and that requests have to go through Apache. In that case, I think that deploying a new webapp and making it visible to the Internet will involve the edit of Apache configuration files (`mod_jk`?, `mod_proxy`?). You should either give us more details or discuss this with your hosting provider.

**Update:** As expected, the `bilgin.ath.cx` is using Apache Tomcat + Apache HTTPD + [mod_jk](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/apache.html). The configuration usually involves two files: the `worker.properties` file to configure the workers and the `httpd.conf` for Apache. Now, without seeing the current configuration, it's not easy to give a definitive answer but, basically, you may have to add a `JkMount` directive in Apache `httpd.conf` for your new webapp<sup>1</sup>. Refer to the [mod_jk](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/apache.html) documentation, it has a simple configuration example. Note that modifying `httpd.conf` will require access to (obviously) and proper rights and that you'll have to restart Apache after the modifications.

<sub><sup>1</sup> I don't think you'll need to define a new worker if you are deploying to an already used Tomcat instance, especially if this sounds like Chinese for you :)</sub>

Comment: @Yatendra I really do **not** recommend to put sensible information on a public website, even for a short time period. And you shouldn't give access to sensible resources to someone you don't know, even if I'm actually a nice guy :)

Answer (score 12):

- copy the .war file in the `webapps` folder
- upload the file using the manager application - `http://host:port/manager`. You will have to setup some users beforehand.
- (not recommended, but working) - manually extract the .war file as a .zip archive and place the extracted files in `webapps/webappname`

Sometimes administrators configure tomcat so that war files are deployed outside the tomcat folder. Even in that case:

After you have it deployed (check the `/logs` dir for any problems), it should be accessible via: `http://host:port/yourwebappname/`. So in your case, one of those:

```
http://bilgin.ath.cx/TestWebApp/
http://bilgin.ath.cx:8080/TestWebApp/
```

If you don't manage by doing the above and googling - turn to your support. There might be an alternative port, or there might be something wrong with the application (and therefore in the logs)

Answer (score 3):

The [tomcat manual](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.0-doc/appdev/deployment.html) says:

> Copy the web application archive file into directory $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/. When Tomcat is started, it will automatically expand the web application archive file into its unpacked form, and execute the application that way.

Comment: after uploading it to the webapps directory, what URL should I enter in the browser to access it index.html page........ I am new to J2EE

Comment: btw, tomcat 4 is outdated ;) (the above statement is still correct for 6)

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can [deploy remotely using HTTP](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/manager-howto.html#Deploy%20A%20New%20Application%20Remotely).

> http://localhost:8080/manager/deploy
>
> Upload the web application archive
>   (WAR) file that is specified as the
>   request data in this HTTP PUT request,
>   install it into the appBase directory
>   of our corresponding virtual host, and
>   start it using the war file name
>   without the .war extension as the
>   path. The application can later be
>   undeployed (and the corresponding
>   application directory removed) by use
>   of the /undeploy. To deploy the ROOT
>   web application (the application with
>   a context path of "/"), name the war
>   ROOT.war.

and if you're using Ant you can do this using [Tomcat Ant tasks](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/manager-howto.html#Executing%20Manager%20Commands%20With%20Ant) (perhaps following a successful build).

To determine which path you then hit on your browser, you need to know the port Tomcat is running on, the context and your servlet path. See [here for more details](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html).

Comment: Your FTP location (as listed in your question) is largely meaningless in this context. What's the port number that Tomcat is running on, what's your servlet name and what's your context name ? These go to make up the path that you request in your browser. See my edit above.

Comment: Secondly, does FTPing it result in a deployment ? You need to write to the correct directory and then check your log files.

Answer (score 1):

Log in :URL =  "localhost:8080/"
Enter username and pass word
Click Manager App
Scroll Down and find  "WAR file to deploy"
Chose file and click deploy

Done

Go to Webapp folder of you Apache tomcat you will see a folder name matching with your war file name.

Type link in your url address bar:: localhost:8080/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.html and press enter

Done