# How To Deploy A Typesafe Activator Application With Tomcat 7.x?

Tags: scala, tomcat, playframework-2.0, war, typesafe-activator

Following the typesafe [Using the dist task](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ProductionDist) to create a standalone version of the activator application tar file and then renamed the extension to `.war`

`$ activator universal:package-zip-tarball`

Following this [stackoverflow user suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217693/how-to-deploy-a-java-web-application-war-on-tomcat?answertab=active#tab-top) to deploy a war application on tomcat results in a `HTTP Status 404` when I visit localhost:8080/app_name

How to deploy a Typesafe activator standalone war application on Tomcat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try searching for how to deploy a play application, such as this result: http://www.poornerd.com/2013/12/06/how-to-run-a-play-framework-application-in-tomcat-or-jboss/
There they point to an sbt plugin to make a war.

`activator` is the build tool (a frontend for sbt), like maven or gradle. So it can be used to make apps that aren't even web apps. When using activator, you can use sbt plugins such as the war plugin here: https://github.com/play2war/play2-war-plugin

When you use `universal:package-zip-tarball` you are using the sbt-native-packager plugin:
https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager
This does not make a valid war file (it isn't just a matter of the filename, it's a matter of what's in the archive, so you can't just rename it).

So in brief:

- you have a Play Framework app, not an activator app
- you're building it with activator, which is an sbt frontend
- so you need an sbt plugin to create a war from a Play Framework app

With that understanding in mind I bet you'll have a lot more luck googling! Good luck.