# How to deploy a new WAR file in Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, ant, war

I am attempting to deploy a new war file to my tomcat server, but I am not seeing my changes reflected. Here is my workflow:

1. Added additional logging in the code.
2. run the following Ant tasks: clean/dist-dev/generate-war
3. Stop the Apache Tomcat service
4. Drop the newly generated .war file into the webapps folder.
5. Start the Apache Tomcat service.

Results: the web application starts normally, but my new logging functionality is not reflected in the log files. Am I missing a step?

Comment: did you delete the exploded war file in the webapps folder?

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217693/how-to-deploy-a-java-web-application-war-on-tomcat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try deleting previous war file that has been extracted in your webapps directory. Then add new .war and restart the Tomcat.