# How to deploy a java web Application?

Tags: java, web-applications, hosting

I have a `domain` and a `web Application`, can I host it directly on to the domain or is there any requirements? Sorry that it may be simple question but I am new to it. If possible provide me a link which describes it?

1. Do I have to have tomcat server in my domain in order to run the application, 
   or is there any other requirements for hosting it?
2. Is there any other way to do it?

I didn't ever deployed a java web Application, can any one explain me?

Comment: Did you ever run your web application on your machine and access it via the browser?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deploy a Java Web Application (.war) on tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217693/how-to-deploy-a-java-web-application-war-on-tomcat)

Comment: *"do i have to have tomcat server"* No, any Servlet container will do. --- *"is there any requirements to host it"* Yes, a server, with an OS, and Java, and a Servlet container, and the domain name mapped to the server.

Comment: yes i did@Thomas but did not deploy it on internaet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways of deploying java application. The simplest one is:

Development Machine:
1. Install Netbeans or Eclipse IDE
2. Follow the process in respective website "how to open your webapp' in IDE.
3. Build your app.
4. In the dist folder you will get yourapp.war file

On Server
1. Install Java and tomcat
2. Copy the war file in tomcat/webapp folder
3. Restart Tomcat

That's it. your app should be running.

Further details and troubleshooting [Click Here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/deployer-howto.html)

Comment: i did it using eclipse in my local host how to do it on web?

Comment: No need to install eclipse on server. Build your app on eclipse on local machine. That will generate yourappname.war file in build/dist folder. Just place this war file on your server (tomcat/webapp). and restart tomcat.

Comment: tq for the information @ Sudeep nayak

Comment: we have linux server ,is it possible to install tomcat there?

Comment: Yes we can do it. Refer [this](https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-centos-7). It may help you.

Answer (score 2):

To run a WebApp over a *domain*, you need a *hosting* and a *domain*. The *domain* is just the name of your website: `yourdomain.xyz`.
The hosting is the space on a web server. Most hosters offer the possibility to register a domain and rent some webspace where the domain directly points to.

[This](https://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/12/hosting-java-applications-in-the-web/) Article talks about different Java Hosting possibilities.

And [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-webapp-runner) article guides you through the setup process, if you want to use webapp runner.

On the oracle website you will find more informations about java web technologies.